# Djago - Access related_name in queryset using as_manager

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am having some difficulty figuring out how to use foreign key (related_name) in a queryset using as_manager()

Below is the mode and queryset. Everything works except the `get_powerbars()' method. I cannot seem to find any information about how to access the reverse foreign key lookup. Anything I try gets me the error (or similar)

'PowerbarQuerySet' object has no attribute 'outlet'

What am I missing? If 'related_name' is not available in a queryset, how would one go about returning all the powerbars and their outlets in a simple fashion.

```
import logging
from django.db import models

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class PowerbarQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    """Additional queryset functions"""

    def get_powerbar_ips(self):
        try:
            all_bars = (
                self.all().values_list("ip", flat=True).order_by("ip")
            )
            return list(all_bars)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            return None


    def get_powerbars(self):
        try:
            all_outlets = (
                self.all().outlet
            )
            return all_outlets
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            return None


class Powerbar(models.Model):

    objects = PowerbarQuerySet.as_manager()

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    building = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    group =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return f'{self.name} @ {self.ip}'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

    class Meta:
        base_manager_name = 'objects'


class PowerbarOutlet(models.Model):

    powerbar = models.ForeignKey(Powerbar, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='outlet')
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    label = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("powerbar", "number")
        ordering = ("powerbar", "number")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return f'{self.number} @ {self.powerbar}'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.powerbar}'
```

I have tried as many solution that I can find and nothing seems to work. The docs don't seem to shed light how to do this.

Comment: It should be powerbaroutlet_set. [Following relationships “backward”](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Comment: Isn't that what "related_name" does? Instead of using the _set you use the related_name. In any case using powerbaroutlet_set causes the same error, 'PowerbarQuerySet' object has no attribute 'powerbaroutlet_set'

Answer (score 0):

You can query the model in reverse:

```
class PowerbarQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    """Additional queryset functions"""

    def get_powerbar_ips(self):
        return self.values_list('ip', flat=True).order_by('ip')

    def get_powerbars(self):
        return PowerbarOutlet.objects.filter(powerbar__in=self.values('pk'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't structure the data is a useful fashion for this project. This presents all the outlets with their associated bars, not the other way around, a list of the bars and their associated outlets. It also doesn't answer the question about why "related_name" can't be used in a queryset/manager situation.

Comment: @archdata: because a `related_name` works with a single modle *object*, not a queryset of these objects. If your `get_powerbars` should return `PowerbarOutlet`s, like the question seems to imply (with `.outlet` and `all_outlet`s), then you make a query that works with the `PowerbarOutlet` as model to query against.

Comment: If you want the bars with the corresponding outlets, you just use `.prefetch_related('powerbaroutlet_set')`, this will return `Powerbar` objects, with each a `.powerbaroutlet_set.all()` available to get the corresponding outlets.

Comment: Still errors:

Cannot find 'powerbaroutlet_set' on Powerbar object, 'powerbaroutlet_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related().

The issue isn't that this query works in a "normal" context, it's that there doesn't seem to be a straight forward way of accessing the related_name or seemingly _set in a queryset/manager. It looks like the context doesn't get passed to a custom manager.

Comment: @archdata, ah, you set a `related_name`, then it is `.prefetch_related('outlet')`.